# maven - How to build uberjars with dependencies

Tags: maven, applet, uberjar

I have a maven module generating a jar file. I have been asked to develop a couple of other uberjar files
as a byproduct of build process. I have also been told these 2 jar files are applet jar files that 
will be need include some classes from the dependencies of the maven module.

I looked around and narrowed down to these 3 options -

1. [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)  - This can build custom jars from the classes generated by the maven module. Third party dependencies cant be included.
2. Use ant through Maven - Use [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to unpack dependencies and then pack the applet jars through ant scripts.
3. Use [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) - Although this plugin is not directly suited for my requirement, I can get it working.

While I can get things working with (b) and (c), I am unable to decide which one to use. One key thing I have noticed is using the dependency plugin is time consuming.

I wanted to know if there are other ways people achieve the same requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include dependencies using the assembly plugin with the `dependencySet` elements, see:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet

Specifically here's an example taken from [Andrew E Bruno's blog](http://left.subtree.org/2008/01/24/creating-executable-jars-with-maven/):

```
<dependencySets>
  <dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    <outputFileNameMapping></outputFileNameMapping>
    <unpack>true</unpack>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <includes>
      <include>commons-lang:commons-lang</include>
      <include>commons-cli:commons-cli</include>
    </includes>
  </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the assembly plugin using the same approach you described above. 
I moved away from shade plugin since I generate several assemblies with resources from outside of maven also and shade plugin does not have great support for such tasks.

Comment: Why not accept Chris White's answer instead of creating your own?