# Create runnable jar from spring application

Tags: spring, jar, jetty

I have created a Spring MVC application with embedded jetty.

Now I need to create a runnable jar able to start the server.

I tried to create a runnable jar from eclipse, but for whatever request I get 404 Not Found.
If I create a normal jar the maven dependencies are not included so I cannot even fur the jar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What build tool do you use? Maven, Ant, ...?

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096723/maven-how-to-build-uberjars-with-dependencies